# git squash diverged from tracked branch

Tags: git, squash

I'm trying to squash some commits from a branch I'm tracking from a github repository (and also in my internal gitolite server). My problem is that I'm rebasing as explained at http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Squashing-Commits, squash is done, but then my branch diverges from github one and I can't push changes to it.

Initially I have my branch updated:

```
amateo@joshua:~/puppetcode/apache$ git status
On branch squash_test
Your branch is up-to-date with 'github/squash_test'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    nohup.out
    spec.log
    spec/acceptance/nodesets.kk/
    tests/spec_dot.pp

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

This is my log:

```
commit 121881d85b93a0b6b851a33d2cc0321196b90f6d
Author: Angel L. Mateo <myemail>
Date:   Tue May 27 11:31:24 2014 +0200

  Add apache::dotconf parameters' documentation

commit c51f6b268a8b22e2c84f93d95ee0b98599770269
Author: Angel L. Mateo <myemail>
Date:   Tue May 27 11:31:24 2014 +0200

  Add apache::dotconf parameters' documentation

commit 82f76d50795eed9839b88745dbabfebe55d8e6bf
Author: Angel L. Mateo <myemail>
Date:   Tue May 27 11:29:19 2014 +0200

  errata

commit 0c3f836e09bb30dac7a969b9d71176bb2e393a73
Author: Angel L. Mateo <myemail>
Date:   Tue May 27 10:58:03 2014 +0200

  Add apache::dotconf documentation

commit bce9951f34c04c8dc0e63ae59dc6922ec70866c2
Author: Angel L. Mateo <myemail>
Date:   Mon May 26 14:47:14 2014 +0200

  A more complete acceptance test.

...
```

Now, I'm doing the rebase with:

```
amateo@joshua:~/puppetcode/apache$ git rebase -i -k --no-ff -m HEAD~6
```

in the edit screen:

```
pick 9e027da Fix allignment                                                          
squash 35cb85e Move template to fixtures directory (as it is only for rspec tests)   
squash bce9951 A more complete acceptance test.                                      
squash 0c3f836 Add apache::dotconf documentation                                     
squash 82f76d5 errata                                                                
squash c51f6b2 Add apache::dotconf parameters' documentation                         
squash 121881d Add apache::dotconf parameters' documentation                         

# Rebase b1ddc75..121881d onto b1ddc75                                               
...
```

rebase is done and I get:

```
[detached HEAD 9f1ce65] Fix allignment
 4 files changed, 101 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
 rename {templates => spec/fixtures/templates}/spec.erb (100%)
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/squash_test.
```

but then, my branch has diverged from upstream, so I can't push those changes:

```
amateo@joshua:~/puppetcode/apache$ git status
On branch squash_test
Your branch and 'github/squash_test' have diverged,
and have 1 and 11 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
...
```

Then, If I run git pull, commit changes are lost.

Any help?

Comment: It seems that a `git push github +squash_test` do what I need

Answer (score 1):

You're changing git history here. You either need to force the push (thereby overriding the remote history), or push your changes to a new branch. I usually do the latter whenever a rebase is needed.

Also, make sure you do a `git pull` before you rebase.